# While updating an app from App Store do **UUID** get **change**?

Tags: ios

I have check the other solution and found out the UUID changes but I have installed and deleted the app and found out it remains same.Want to conform wether it change while updating the app from app store?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not change. But that it's now deprecated.

if the Application is completely remove from the Device then only UUID is Change, otherwise Remain Same and its also gets changed when app is overwritten by TestFlight over AppStore vise-versa.

Here is the Diff between **UUID** & **UDID**.

**UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier)** Is on a per-app basis. identifies an app on a device. As long as the user doesn’t completely delete the app, then this identifier will persist between app launches, and at least let you identify the same user using a particular app on a device. Unfortunately, if the user completely deletes and then reinstalls the app then the ID will change.

**UDID (Unique Device Identifier)** A sequence of 40 hexadecimal characters that uniquely identify an ios device. This value can be retrieved through iTunes, or found using UIDevice -uniqueIdentifier. Derived from hardware details like MAC address.